# Changing the value of select2 in x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

I want to change the value of my select2 in x-editable.

This is what i have done so far

**HTML**

```
<td><a href="#" class="job-status" data-type="select2" data-pk="<?= $job->id; ?>" data-value="<?= $job->status; ?>" data-title="Assign Status"></a></td>
```

It is a cell in a table, thus it may have more than 1 select2 inside the table.

**Javascript**

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
 var status = [];
$.each({"open" : "Open", "filled" : "Filled", "closed" : "Closed"}, function(k, v) {
 status.push({id: k, text: v});
}); 

$('a.job-status').each(function(){
    $(this).editable({
     source: status,
     url: '<?= base_url(); ?>bunker/jobstatus/',
     select2: {
         width: 100,
         placeholder: 'Assign Status',
         allowClear: true
     },
     ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST'
     },
     success: function(response, newValue){
        if(!response){
            return "Unknown error!";
        }

        if(response.status === false){
            return response.message;
        }else{
            return response.message;
        }
     }
    });
});
```

});

The server side is working just fine. The data is changed as it suppose to be. The only problem that i am having is, i want the value of my select2 changed once it has received the correct response from the server.

At the moment, if the inital value of my select2 is 'open' it will not be updated regardless the response it received from the server.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: hi, you want to change the value of select2 after success ajax response ? this is what i understand.

Comment: I think your JavaScript is not bind with your select2, otherwise it is simplest way of set the value in select2 e.g 
$("#id_of_select2").select2('data', {id: 100, a_key: 'Lorem Ipsum'});